# Как в C обрабатывать клавиатуру и мышь?

Tags: c, c99

Как можно реализовать обработку мыши и клавиатуры на C99, встречал например в GTK и вроде в SDL и мне всегда было интересно как же это реализуется.
Пока больше нечего по вопросу добавить.

> Upd

Я тут узнал что в linux устройства как мышь и клавиатура называются символьными устройствами и каждое устройство представлено узлом символьного устройства, то-есть это единственный способ взаимодействия ? И правильный ?

Comment: Сам по себе C (как и C++) не представляет средств для работы ни с клавиатурой, ни с мышью. Используйте системно-зависимые библиотеки.

Comment: Например какие?

Comment: Например WinAPI.

Comment: @VladD а на Linux ?

Comment: Линукс сам по себе, как я понимаю, не предоставляет графического интерфейса. А вот иксы предоставляют. Ну или может быть какая-нибудь более высокоуровневая обёртка, тут уж я не в курсе.

Comment: Может быть, вас интересует то, как мышь и клавиатура обрабатываются в операционной системе? Тогда вам нужно изучить тему портов, интерфейсов и прерываний.

Comment: Запросы в гугл типа `linux console mouse c program example` выводят на [Mouse Programming with libgpm](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4600). Также полезен запрос `xterm mouse escape sequences`, из которого выходим на http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html ,  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html , http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_ioctl.4.html и https://linux.die.net/man/8/gpm

Comment: @CGLike,   *"то-есть это единственный способ взаимодействия ? И правильный ?"* -- нет, а если обрисуете какую-то *конкретную* задачку, которую хотите запрограммировать  (в Linux), то скорее всего получите ответ. А еще, можно взять сорсы, например **mc**, и посмотреть как они это делают